# How can a web developer contribute to Ubuntu?

Tags: development, community, contributing

I've done web development for the past ten years, and have used Ubuntu for my operating system for the past five. I feel like my design and development skills could be useful, but don't know how I can help with experience in web development. I'm currently versed in Ruby, PHP, ColdFusion, and Javascript, and I took a Java class in college. I'm also willing to learn a new language, but don't even know where to start as far as what would be most helpful to the Ubuntu community.

Are there projects that a web developer could help with in Ubuntu? Or what language should I learn to best help contribute?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do as far as contributing, but if nothing else, helping others with related problems in the forums can also contribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to tweak the kernel, you can use [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) or [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), these are some of the most used programming languages in the linux world. Since you already know PHP and Javascript, I would recommend Python, since it's easy to use and easier to start with.

You don't actually need to learn another programming language, you can help the comunity in many ways:

#### - [Ubuntu Comunity](http://www.ubuntu.com/community)

#### - [Comunity Teams](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Teams)

If you want to start developing code, you can check the [Ubuntu Development](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment), it explains the starting points, communication and overall start point for developers.

You can also check [this section](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/get-involved) on Ubuntu.com to find out all the ways you can help the community.

Comment: And isn't Ruby built off/inspired by Python? I could be mistaken

Comment: @KyleMacey Actually, Ruby was inspired by perl.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish, you can branch and make tweaks or fix bugs in:

- [Ubuntu Summit Portal](https://launchpad.net/summit)
- [Ubuntu Local Community Teams (LoCos) Portal](https://launchpad.net/loco-team-portal)
- [Ubuntu Font Family website](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-family-website)
- [Ubuntu Start Page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-start-page)
- [Ubuntu Developer Portal](https://launchpad.net/ubuntudeveloperportal)
- …and so on. There may be more websites you can provide feedback or fixes if you want. You’ll see how much fun it is to contribute!